# C# VSTO Excel Auto Filter on Value and Blanks

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, autofilter

I have the following auto filter code in my C# to filter an excel column in VSTO. Currently I am checking for column 11 and filtering on the value 'Never Out Of Stock' but i also want to filter on any blank cells. How do I adjust the below code to filter on the value Never Out Of Stock and blanks. Currently its not including blanks in the filter.

```
xlrange.AutoFilter(11, "Never Out Of Stock", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd,Type.Missing, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xlrange.AutoFilter(11, "Never Out Of Stock", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlOr, "=", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.autofilter?view=excel-pia):

> Use "=" to find blank fields, or use "<>" to find nonblank fields.

So your code should be:

```
xlrange.AutoFilter(11, "Never Out Of Stock", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlOr, "=", true);
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work - sorry i just re-tested and it doesn't include blanks and the never out of stock in one filter. According to the documentation = is criteria 1. So let me try swapping them around

Comment: Needs to be xlOr not xlAnd